# Fixing android listview size to a particular length

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-relativelayout

I have created a layout file . There are other layout included in it .
  There is    one   list view also in it. I am giving fix height to it.
  its working fine in my screen   but when we use it to other screen size
  its not shown on full . how can it will work for all size devices.
 code is given below.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/mainScreenHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/main_screen_header" />


    <include
        android:id="@+id/mainScreenListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainScreenHeader"
        layout="@layout/main_screen_list_header" >
    </include>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainScreenListHeader"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

     <include
        android:id="@+id/mainScreenFilterClient"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        layout="@layout/main_screen_filter_client" >
    </include>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainScreenFilterClient"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        layout="@layout/footer" >
    </include>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try using android:weight , so that your listview can be resized according to your screen dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

you have to predecide no of rows according to the device screen size and then calculate the height for each row.you should not explicitly give the android:layout_height="270dp".
you can get the height of screen  and to decide the no of rows in list view can refer this :

```
    private int retrieveDimensions() {
        int noOfRows= 0;
        int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

        switch(screenSize) {
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE:
            noOfRows= 5;
            break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
            noOfRows= 4;
            break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
            noOfRows= 3;
            break;
    }
```